# Current flow in a circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

I'm confused in a basic concept in current electricity. Suppose I have two situations-

[image]

In situation **A**, the points A and B are not necessarily equipotential. So a current can flow through the wire AB. But in this case, we can treat the resistor combinations(in series)-(R1,R2) and (R3,R4) to be in parallel. But in situation **B**, there is resistor *R5* in branch AB, so the respective resistor combinations are not in parallel. Why does this happen, and why do they remain in parallel connection in **A** and not in **B**? Why does a resistor in branch *AB* in situation **B** make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let us assume there is a potential difference across $A$ and $B$, then there is a current $i$ across it, now if you apply the formula $R$ $=$ $\cfrac{|V_{A}-V_{B}|}{I}$ you would get a resistance of conducting wire , which is not possible so a conducting wire must have equal potential across its terminals ( this is in ideal case)

Comment: Since R1 and R4 have different values, therefore potential at A and B must have different values. How do you explain this? If A and B were to be equipotential, current would never have flown through the branch AB, but current does flow through AB.

Comment: @Abhinav Tahlani actually current through R1 and R4 have different values , but potential difference across them is same

Comment: @Abhinav Tahlani I would make it easier ever seen hc verma lecture on current without potential difference search it on you tube